# convert list to string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

I'm trying to convert a list of integers to string. And it shows me the above error. What am I doing wrong?

Expected output:  10,5,78

```
l=[10,5,78]
s=''
for i in l:
    s=s.join(i)
print(s)
```

Comment: As the error message says, `s.join` "can only join an iterable". Is the `i` an iterable? No, it's an integer, and integers cannot be iterated over. You can just do `s = str(l)[1:-1]`, for example

Comment: `l = [10,5,78]; ",".join([str(i) for i in l])`

Comment: @ForceBru That worked like magic. Can you please explain what [1:-1] does?

Comment: @VishalPallikonda, it converts `l` to the string `"[10, 5, 78]"` and returns its characters except the first (`1`) and the last (`-1`) ones (the brackets). The `[1:-1]` syntax is called _slicing_

Comment: @ForceBru this solution gives extra space after comma and so doesn’t fit the expected output and it also doesn’t help VishalPallikonda learn the join syntax.

Comment: You just need `s = ''.join(str(_) for _ in l)` or `s = ','.join(str(_) for _ in l)`, if you want the numbers comma separated.

Comment: @Tim, the output is very close, though (I'm 90% sure the spaces don't matter that much here), and it's simple to make it match the desired output exactly: `str(l)[1:-1].replace(' ', '')`

Comment: @ForceBru It’s an interesting and imaginative solution. There is no doubt :) But I think for beginners it’s better to master the basics before trying something fancy like this ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Join doesn’t work the way you think it works.

What join does:

`",".join(["a", "b", "c"])`

Gives `"a,b,c"`. Essentially it creates a string by elements from a list with what you provided before `.join`, in this case it’s a comma.

So what you want can be achieved by

`",".join(str(x) for x in l)`

The inside expression changes the integers in list `l` into strings before joining them by comma.

Answer (score 2):

`.join()` method acts on an existing string and accepts a list of strings. Join every item of the given list separated by the string acting on.

```py
>>> l = [10, 5, 78]
>>> l = [str(i) for i in l]    # map to a list of strings
>>> s = ','.join(l)            # join all the strings separated by a comma
>>> s
'10,5,78'
```