# Convert a list of string into one string such that if any string present inside list has space then it will be a string in output string

Tags: python

I have list like :

Input=['Name', 'Friendly Name', 'Place']

I want to convert it into a string like:

Output='Name, "Friendly Name", Place'

How can I do this in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a list to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906092/converting-a-list-to-a-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert list to string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59591503/convert-list-to-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this :

```
Input=['Name', 'Friendly Name', 'Place']
Input = ['"' + name + '"' if name.count(' ') > 0 else name for name in Input ]
", ".join(Input)

#result : 'Name, "Friendly Name", Place'
```

Answer (score 2):

To turn a list into a string, like 0buz mentions you should use the `join()` method of string objects.

```py
", ".join(Input)
```

To quote strings with spaces in them, you can use a list comprehension to create a copy of the list with the necessary changes:

```py
[ f'"{s}"' if ' ' in s else s for s in Input]
```

This iterates over each item `s` in the list `Input`, checking if ' ' (a space) is in the item. If it is, we concatenate a `"` to the beginning and end of the `s` and then append it to our list. Otherwise, we just append the item `s` unchanged.

Putting them together:

```py
Output = ", ".join([ f'"{s}"' if ' ' in s else s for s in Input])
```

Comment: Slightly simpler (in my opinion) using an f-string: `', '.join(f'"{x}"' if ' ' in x else x for x in Input)`.

Comment: That's actually far better, thanks for the suggestion. I'll edit the answer.